# Gaussian blur with svg and css over image slider

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

Apparently there is no native way to have a gaussian blur which affects non-absolute positioned images, svg is a good choice in this case. But for some reason it doesn't work here.

I want to have a gaussian blur over the slider like you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1tDG.jpg

The div with class blur is the one I want the svg filter to be applied, here is my code:

```css
/*SLIDER AMA START*/
.slider_ama_maincontainer{width:100%; height:92vh; position:relative; overflow:hidden; display:flex;}
.slider_ama_nav_container{width:100%; height:75px;  z-index:99999; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; display:flex; align-items:center;}
.slider_ama_nav_links_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; align-items:center; margin-left:auto;}
.slider_ama_nav_link{font-size:18px; font-weight:400; display:flex; align-items:center;  text-shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);  height:100%; transition:all 300ms ease; padding:0px 25px; background-color:none; color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0); margin:0px 0px;}
.slider_ama_nav_link:hover{background-color:var(--web_primary_color);}
.slider_ama_prev{position:absolute; width:auto; height:auto;  top:50%; border-radius:0px; transform:translateY(-50%); left:5px; z-index:9999; display:flex; background-color:none;}
.slider_ama_next{position:absolute; width:auto; height:auto; top:50%; border-radius:0px; transform:translateY(-50%); right:5px; z-index:9999; display:flex; background-color:none;}
.slider_ama_prev .fa{font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin:auto;}
.slider_ama_next .fa{font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin:auto;}
.slider_ama_navigation_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; align-items:center; border-radius:5px; justify-content:center; position:absolute; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); padding:10px 25px; bottom:90px; right:25px; z-index:9999;}
.slider_ama_items_container{width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; overflow:hidden; background-color:black;}
.slider_ama_item{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.slider_ama_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.slider_ama_image{width:100%; height:100%;  background-size:cover; position:relative; background-position:center; z-index:998;}
.slider_ama_text_container{min-width:40%; height:auto; padding:30px; display:flex;  flex-direction:column; border-radius:5px; z-index:9999; position:absolute; background-color:none;}
.slider_ama_text_title{font-size:35px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:400; border-radius:5px; padding:15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); text-shadow:2px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
.slider_ama_text_description{font-size:25px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:400; border-radius:5px; padding:15px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); text-shadow:2px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
.slider_ama_text_link{font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin-bottom:15px; align-self:center; font-weight:400; border-radius:5px; padding:15px; background-color:var(--web_primary_color); text-shadow:2px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
.prev{transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:1;}
.next{transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:1;}
.container:hover .prev{opacity:1;}
.container:hover .next{opacity:1;}
.slider_active{display:flex; opacity:1;}
.slider_active_dot{background-color:white;}
.dot{width:15px; height:15px;  border-radius:50%; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); transition: all 2000ms ease; margin:0px 10px; cursor:pointer;}
/*SLIDER AMA END*/
.slider_ama_top_banner{width:100%; height:150px; top:0px; outline:1px solid red; left:0px; display:flex; position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px; z-index:99999;}

.blur {
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');
        -webkit-filter: url(#blur-filter);
        filter: url(#blur-filter);
        -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
        filter: blur(3px);
    }
```

```html
<section class="slider_ama_maincontainer" style="">
 <div class="slider_ama_items_container container" style="">
  <div class="slider_ama_items_bottom_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
     <div class="slider_ama_navigation_container navigation" style="">
      <a class="slider_ama_prev prev" href="" style=""><i class="fas fa fa-chevron-left" style=""></i></a>
         <a class="slider_ama_next next" href="" style=""><i class="fas fa fa-chevron-right" style=""></i></a>
  </div>
     <div class="slider_ama_item slider" style="">
      <div class="slider_ama_gradient_overlay" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);" ></div>
      <div class="slider_ama_image move" style="background-image:url('https://morukuru.com/wp-content/uploads/AtholPlace-Restaurant.jpg');"></div>
      <div class="slider_ama_text_container top_to_bottom_center" style="">
       <span class="slider_ama_text_title" style="">{{ Config::get('globals.slider_title_1') }}</span>
       <span class="slider_ama_text_description" style="">{{ Config::get('globals.slider_description_1') }}</span>
    <a href="" class="slider_ama_text_link" style="">Interesting link</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_ama_nav_container" style="">
         <div class="slider_ama_nav_links_container" style="">
          <a class="slider_ama_nav_link" href="/" style="">Principal</a>
    <a class="slider_ama_nav_link" href="/nuestra-carta-de-menus" style="">Menu</a>
    <a class="slider_ama_nav_link" href="/horario-de-apertura" style="">Horario</a>
    <a class="slider_ama_nav_link" href="/" style="">Localización</a>
    <a class="slider_ama_nav_link" href="/" style="">Contactar</a>
    <a class="slider_ama_nav_link" href="/" style="">Reseñas</a>
      </div>
     </div>
  <div class="slider_ama_top_banner blur" style="">
  
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur-filter">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3"></feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Clearly the blur in the example is in the photo itself. Anyway, css filters will affect the element itself, not what's behind it. You could apply the blur to the image or the element that has the image as background.

Comment: Suggest reading this: https://codeburst.io/ios-backdrop-effect-on-chrome-and-non-webkit-browsers-summary-of-currently-available-techniques-34b0f624ae6a